# How to update slack interactive message based on user response

Tags: python, flask, slack

I am new to slack API and I am trying to implement interactive messages using slash command with the help of flask and python.
I am stuck at the last step where I want to update the original message instead of replacing it.

Every time I send a response on button click, the original message is replaced.

I am able to retrieve original_message from payload but not sure how to append a user response to that message. Here is my code:

```
@application.route("/summarize", methods=['POST'])    
def hello():
    attach_json = {
    "response_type": "in_channel",
    "text": "Interested in outing?",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "text": "Response",
            "fallback": "You are unable to choose any option",
            "callback_id": "confirmation",
            "color": "#3AA3E3",
            "attachment_type": "default",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "name": "confirm_btn",
                    "text": "Yes",
                    "type": "button",
                    "value": "yes"
                },
                {
                    "name": "confirm_btn",
                    "text": "No",
                    "type": "button",
                    "value": "No"
                },
                {
                    "name": "confirm_btn",
                    "text": "Can't decide",
                    "type": "button",
                    "value": "unavailable"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
    print(request.get_data())
    #return Response("test", status=200)
    return Response(response=json.dumps(attach_json), status=200, mimetype="application/json")

@application.route("/actions", methods=['POST'])
def actions():
    statement = None
    slack_req = json.loads(request.form.get('payload'))
    response = '{"text": "Hi, <@' + slack_req["user"]["id"] + '>"}'

    user = slack_req["user"]["name"]
    user_response = slack_req["actions"][0]["value"]
    orig_message = slack_req["original_message"]

    if user_response == "yes":
        statement = user + "chose " + user_response


    print(slack_req)
    return Response(response=statement, status=200, mimetype="application/json")




if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(debug=True)
```

Will really appreciate any help!

Comment: What exactly is printed and what requests are being made, and when?

Comment: Since my code only supports yes option i.e. first button, it displays "username chose yes". I am not sure what you meant by "when" ?

Comment: I mean "when", in time order. Which functions are hit first? You go to the bot, it returns some buttons, you click one, then something else.... Just looking at the code alone, the order of events is not clear

Comment: Aah ok. I input "/summarize" command in slack, I get the required message from hello() with buttons. I click on yes and that's where def actions() takes control  and outputs what is returned by Response(last line) replacing the original message.

Answer (score 0):

> but not sure how to append a user response to that message

Something like this?

```
print("user {} chose {} for original_message='{}'".format(user, user_response, original_message))
```

Comment: I believe print would output on console and not in slack. also, original_message is a dictionary(json format). I will try your suggestion. Thank you for your response :)

Comment: I mean, you can return it as a string or output in other formats, but the solution seems fairly straightforward, given you already have both variables.

Comment: thanks for looking into it @cricket_007. as you said, solution was fairly straightforward. I had to change the json "text" property under "attachments"  this is what I did  orig_message['attachments'][0]['text'] = statement + "\n"

Answer (score 0):

The following statement in

```
 def actions():
```

resolved my query.

```
orig_message['attachments'][0]['text'] = statement + "\n"
return Response(response=json.dumps(orig_message), status=200, mimetype="application/json")
```